# SQL where clause on inner joins

Tags: postgresql, inner-join, where-clause

I am working with pgadminIII (postgreSQL)

I have the following tables:
Book,
Publisher,
OrderLine,
ShopOrder.

With the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
    Book.BookID AS "Book ID"
    ,Book.Title AS "Book title"
    ,SUM(OrderLine.quantity) AS "Number Ordered"
    ,ShopOrder.OrderDate AS "Order Date"
FROM (((Book

INNER JOIN OrderLine
ON Book.BookID = OrderLine.BookID)

INNER JOIN Publisher
ON Book.PublisherID = Publisher.PublisherID )


INNER JOIN ShopOrder
ON OrderLine.ShopOrderID = ShopOrder.ShopOrderID)

GROUP BY ShopOrder.OrderDate, Name, Book.BookID

.
```

I would like to use this with a (`WHERE Publisher.Name = "Smith Smitheson"`)

I dont know where to put it, or if im doing it right, any help please?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
...
INNER JOIN Publisher ON Book.PublisherID = Publisher.PublisherID AND Publisher.Name = 'Smith Smitheson' )
...
```

or

```
SELECT Book.BookID AS "Book ID" ,Book.Title AS "Book title"   
,SUM(OrderLine.quantity) AS "Number Ordered" ,ShopOrder.OrderDate AS  
"Order Date" FROM Book
INNER JOIN OrderLine ON Book.BookID = OrderLine.BookID
INNER JOIN Publisher ON Book.PublisherID = Publisher.PublisherID 
INNER JOIN ShopOrder ON OrderLine.ShopOrderID = ShopOrder.ShopOrderID
WHERE Publisher.Name = 'Smith Smitheson'
GROUP BY ShopOrder.OrderDate, Name, Book.BookID
```